# Is it possible to insert a record in a table with a VARCHAR PK using Anorm?

Tags: mysql, scala, anorm, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to insert a row in a MySQL table like this one:

```
create table CURRENCIES ( 
  code        VARCHAR(3), 
  description VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
);
```

My Scala code is:

```
val pk: Option[String] = DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
  SQL("INSERT INTO currencies (code, description) VALUES ({code}, {description});")
      .on("code" -> code , "description" -> description)
      .executeInsert()
}
```

But I'm getting an error due to an expected numeric PK while I'm using a VARCHAR. I've read about ResultSetParser to achieve such kind of inserts, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
val pk: Option[String] = DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
  SQL("INSERT INTO currencies (code, description) VALUES ({code}, {description});")
    .on("code" -> code , "description" -> description)
    .executeInsert[Option[String]](
                  ResultSetParser.singleOpt[String](
                      anorm.SqlParser.get[String]("1")
                  )
              )
```

}